# how to geocode phone number

Tags: python, geocoding, phone-number

I have a list of phone numbers with area code prefixes that I want to find a latitude/longitude location for.

Is there a library (ideally Python) or service that can do this?

Comment: With VoIP you can't tell anymore :-)

Comment: I can immediately think of at least one person with a phone area code of 415 (normally meaning San Francisco & some environs theeof) who lives in South Carolina (he moved 10 years ago and simply kept his old number: you're entitled to do that, if you just ask!). So I'm not sure how well you can hope to geolocate '415' &c...!-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to obtain limited free information (e.g. town) or, for a hefty fee, some relatively more detailed information (address), from various Whitepages-like providers.  This should cover **landlines** as well as, to some degree, **mobile (cell) lines**.  Be aware that in the case of mobile lines the information (billing address at best, BTW, not terminal location) may be sketchy or even misleading (the numbers can be registered to third-party companies which manages fleets of cell phones for businesses -- companies which may be registered at addresses completely different from those of the businesses using the fleet.)  You would then have to resolve the street address to latitude/longitide, so it would be a two-step process.  As for **VoIP**, you can read about [GEOPRIV](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3693.txt).

Take a look inside [this whitepages.com sample](http://developer.whitepages.com/page/app02) to see how they expect you to interact with their database (I doubt it's what you want, but it's what they offer.)

Comment: another possibility is the Yelp API: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/phone_api